# JSplitPane in NetBean GUI builder

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

I tried to drag a `JSplitPane` from the `Palette` in NetBeans but it always shows up on my `JPanel` as two separate panes with left and right buttons on them.

I could not do anything with the buttons. They were not even components on the `Pane`. What is going on? How could you make it like normal empty two split panes with nothing one them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The buttons are just placeholders. First you resize the pane(including those buttons) to what size and position you desire. Then, just drag a `JPanel` (or any other component) from palette, and drop it on the any of the buttton. That button will be replaced by the `JPanel` (or component). Then you may do anything as you normally do with `JPanel` (or that component).

Comment: How do you resize the damn thing. I can only resize the right-hand size panel. The left size is always the same.

Comment: @chx101 Hi. Considering the original question was about NetBeans I guess you ask this in regard to NetBeans. The only way I managed of doing it was: Place the damn thing ( :p ) on the IDE; resize it to anything (or leave it alone); right click on it->properties-> and set "dividerLocation". You will see changes on that value will change the relative location of the divider at design time.